# System locales and non-unicode programs

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, locale

I have a file in local d drive: d:\système.gz ( This file is generated in different region. Note the è. )

I am trying to open this file using fopen using non-unicode executable. The following code works when System Locale for non-unicode program is set to "English(United States)".

If I change this locale to "Japanese(Japan)" ( under Region Settings ) then fopen fails.

This is how memory looks like for string 'système.gz':

1: English(United States)

```
73 79 73 74 e8 6d 65 2e 67 7a
```

2: Japanese(Japan)

```
73 79 73 74 65 6d 65 2e 67 7a
```

How to handle this situation correctly? Do I have to invoke some API to set the locale in my code?

```
std::string path = "d:";

for (auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(path))
{       
    std::string fName = p.path().filename().string();
    std::string ext = p.path().extension().string();

    if (ext == ".gz")
    {
        std::string drive = "d:\\" ;
        std::string fullPath = drive + fName;
        const char * strPath = fullPath.c_str();
        FILE * fp = fopen(strPath, "rb");
        if (!fp)
        {
            printf("\nNot found\n");
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

If I use:

```
p.path().filename().u8string()
```

Then memory changes to:(but fopen will still fail)

```
73 79 73 74 c3 a8 6d 65 2e 67 7a
```

Comment: If you call ANSI `FindFirstFileA`, as one would expect for a non-Unicode program, filenames will be *best-fit* encoded using the system locale's ANSI codepage. For opening the file, the encoded filename won't necessarily roundtrip (e.g. "è" -> "e") or even be valid (e.g. characters replaced with "?"). You can't control the system locale; changing it requires rebooting. The only solution is to use Unicode functions such as `FindFirstFileW` and `CreateFileW`. Your program can work with UTF-8 and convert to UTF-16 for Windows API calls.

Comment: Use wfopen() or std::wifstream.